# How to get unicode inputs on html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unicode

You can easily get ASCII inputs using jQuery:

```
$('body').keypress(function(e){
    console.log('input: ',String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
});
```

Testing this snippet inputting special characters such as á é í ó ú doesn't give the expected input. How to get get the proper unicode input on HTML?

Comment: Do you mind showing what's the expected "input"?

Comment: Works fine for me. It's likely related to the declared HTML page encoding.

Comment: `Content-Type : text/html; charset=utf-8` ?

Comment: make a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @rid really? You can just get UTF-8 strings from String.fromCharCode() !?

Comment: @Dokkat have you just tried it?

Comment: @feeela I have, it didn't work... I'll try again whem I'm back at work and update you, but sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
String.fromCharCode(225);
```

returns

```
"á"
```

Here is a solution that covers code units of UTF-16, although it says that you shouldn't have a problem, since your characters are all the "usual 2-byte ones":

[developer.mozilla.org: String.fromCodePoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)