# Special characters not working on html keypress events on OSX

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, html

The following page won't work as expected.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $('body').keypress(function(e){
                console.log('char: ',String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Trying to type special characters such as `á é í ó ú` will print `a e i o u` instead.

Comment: Which keys do you press to get the special characters? Each key press is a separate keypress event.

Comment: @bfavaretto The ´ key followed by the e key, producing é (for example).

Comment: If it takes a few keys to get the characters, you may wish to log them all: `$('body').bind('keyup keydown keypress', function(e){ console.log('char: ',String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));});`

Comment: Is there a difference to your yesterdays question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541296/how-to-get-unicode-inputs-on-html-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Note that jQuery documentation of [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) says: “**Note:** as the `keypress` event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.” It also says: “To determine which character was entered, examine the `event` object that is passed to the handler function. While browsers use differing properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the `.which` property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the character code.”

At least on Windows, using `e.which` gives consistent results in browsers, whereas `e.keyCode` does not. And it yields the character entered, e.g. á when I press the acute key (´) and then the A key. If this does not happen in OSX, then the explanation is probably system-level difference in handling keys; you might need to check whether you can then use `keydown` and `keyup` more successfully (they should indicate the keys pressed, and you would need to deduce the character from them in your program logic).