# Detect accented chars typed on Mac?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, keypress

I'm trying emulate an `<input type="text">` in SVG by listening `keypress`es and `keydown`s on the `<body>` of the page.

There seems to be an issue with accented letters on the Mac. You have to type <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> for getting an `á`, and the same for other vowels.

I'm listening on the body [like this (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/6fcexu5j/):

```
var theElement = document;
theElement.onkeypress = function(e) {
    console.log("Press: " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + " " + e.keyCode);
}
theElement.onkeydown = function(e) {
    console.log("Down: " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + " " + e.keyCode);
}
theElement.onkeyup = function(e) {
    console.log("Up: " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + " " + e.keyCode);
}
```

On Windows, typing an `é` I get the following log:

> Down: Þ 222 (index):27
>
> Up: Þ 222 (index):30
>
> Down: E 69 (index):27
>
> Press: é 233 (index):24
>
> Up: E 69 (index):30

And it works OK. But on a Mac I get:

> Down:  18 (index):27
>
> Down: E 69 (index):27
>
> Up: E 69 (index):30
>
> Up:  18 (index):30
>
> Down: E 69 (index):27
>
> Press: e 101 (index):24
>
> Up: E 69

`18` is the <kbd>Option</kbd> key pressed up or down, but it seems to forget the accent is trying to be typed, and I only get a press for the `e` character.

Even weirder, when I attach the same events to an `<input type="text">` box, I get the `é` typed on the `input` (again, in the Mac), but the press event shows a standard `e` instead of an accented one ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv3jj59h/)):

> Down:  18 (index):27
>
> Down: å 229 (index):27
>
> Up: E 69 (index):30
>
> Up:  18 (index):30
>
> Down: å 229 (index):27
>
> Up: E 69 (index):30

And it doesn't matter what accented letter I type (`é`, `á`, you name it), it displays the same 229 code.

The log is exactly the same as the `<body>` one in Windows - ie, it works OK and consistently in both fiddles on Windows.

I'm testing both in a recent Google Chrome (I can't swore it's the latest, but it's kind of up-to-date).

**Halp?!**

Comment: Entering accented characters is highly OS-specific (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14546380/2564301). OSX temporarily saves the accent code and awaits the next key press. If it can find a matching accented character, it sends that to the application; if not, you get *two* characters, first the accent on its own, then the new character.

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the option key

```
var theElement = document;
theElement.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (theElement.accent === true)
        console.log("Press: " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + " (accented) " + e.keyCode);
    else 
        console.log("Press: " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + " " + e.keyCode);
}
theElement.onkeydown = function(e) {
    theElement.accent = true;
    if (theElement.accent === true)
        console.log("Press: " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + " (accented) " + e.keyCode);
    else 
        console.log("Press: " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + " " + e.keyCode);
}
theElement.onkeyup = function(e) {
    theElement.accent = false;
    if (theElement.accent === true)
        console.log("Press: " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + " (accented) " + e.keyCode);
    else 
        console.log("Press: " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + " " + e.keyCode);
}
```

I mean in acctual implementation you would probably want to create a function to get the accented character code from an array or something.